# Column height issue

Tags: html, drupal, css

On my companys website http://www.ensorbuilding.com , the middle content always overlaps the left menu, sometimes the right menu overlaps the other two.

The code looks like this

```
<aside id="left_menu"></aside>
<section id="content"></section>
<aside id="right_menu"></aside>
```

I have used many javascript auto height fixes but none of them seem to have worked?

Can anybody shed some light into this?

Thankyou!

Comment: I cannot see any problem. Can you elaborate? Is this happening on a specific browser?

Comment: What browsers are causing problems? Can you post a screenshot of the problem layout? I'm not clear on why you're assigning specific heights to the columns in the first place.

Comment: This is how I see it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 9 http://imageshack.us/a/img195/2685/problem2xf.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your replies, the left menu element has a background image which i would like to stretch to the "tallest" element of the three

Comment: I can't see a background image ?

Comment: Sorry I meant a background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't seen your code but if I made it, I would affect to the three parts (both menus and content) a fixed width.

For instance in CSS:

```
#left_menu{
float:left;
width:200px
}


#right_menu{
float:left;
width:200px
}


#content{
float:left;
width:600px
}
```

Elements' `height` does not matter for your issue.

Comment: All three elements do have widths set (in percentages). The left menu has a background image which i would like to stretch to the "tallest" element of the three